# What is the size limit for a varchar2 PL/SQL subprogram argument in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

When you create a procedure (or a function) in Oracle PL/SQL, you cannot specify the maximum length of the varchar2 arguments, only the datatype. For example

```
create or replace procedure testproc(arg1 in varchar2) is
begin
  null;
end;
```

Do you know the maximum length of a string that you can pass as the arg1 argument to this procedure in Oracle ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In PL/SQL procedure it may be up to 32KB

Futher information here:
http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/oracle-guide/learn-oracle-sql-and-plsql-datatypes-strings-10804

Comment: Not quite, the real limit is 32767 bytes which is 32KB - 1. The correct answer is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22060657/480894

Answer (score 10):

I tried with testproc( lpad( ' ', 32767, ' ' ) ) and it works.

With 32768 bytes it fails, so it's 32K - 1 bytes

Answer (score 3):

In PL/SQL the maximum size of `VARCHAR2` datatype is **32767 bytes** since 10gR2 (and probably earlier but I just checked the documentation upto that release).

The documentation references:

- Oracle 12cR1: [PL/SQL Language Reference
  12c Release 1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17622/datatypes.htm#LNPLS99943)
- Oracle 11gR2: [PL/SQL Language Reference
  11g Release 2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/datatypes.htm#LNPLS99943)
- Oracle 10gR2: [PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference
  10g Release 2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/datatypes.htm#sthref732)

Comment: Just curious, do you know why not 32Kb instead of 32Kb -1 ?

Comment: @Roland No I don't know. Maybe it's a [null-terminated string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string), maybe something else. Oh and please don't ask why it's 2^15-1 and not 2^16-1. Only Oracle knows. :)

Comment: @Roland, it's because default 2-byte signed integer variable has range from -32768 to 32767.