# Why does an oracle plsql varchar2 variable need a size but a parameter does not?

Tags: oracle, plsql, varchar2

Suppose you have this procedure:

```
PROCEDURE f (param VARCHAR2)
IS 
   var VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
   var := 'hi';
END f;
```

I would like to understand why `var` needs a length specified, but `param` does not. I'm having a hard time finding information about this in the oracle docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Oracle Database derives the length, precision, and scale of an argument from the environment from which the procedure is called."

Please check out this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186403/what-is-the-size-limit-for-a-varchar2-procedure-argument-in-oracle-10g).

Reference: [Oracle® Database SQL Reference 10g Release 2 (10.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm)
Please look under semantics / argument / datatype.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that subprogram headings have *formal parameters* that are replaced with *actual parameters* when the subprogram is called:

```
create or replace function f(
  p_x in varchar2 /* a formal parameter */
 ,p_y in varchar2 /* a formal parameter */
) return varchar2 /* a formal parameter */
is
begin
  return p_x || p_y;
end;

declare
  v_z varchar2(10);
  v_x constant varchar2(1) := 'X';
begin
  v_z := f(v_x, 'Y'); /* actual parameters */
end;
```

The formal parameter is unconstrained (but constrained subtypes can be used) and includes also information about *parameter mode* and possible *default value* that are not relevant when a variable is declared.

The datatypes of formal and actual parameters have not to be the same but *compatible*.

There is plenty of other details too but they can be read from chapter [PL/SQL Subprograms](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/subprograms.htm) of [PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/toc.htm). See expecially *Subprogram Parameters*.

I don't know why the formal parameters have to be unconstrained but I'm a quite happy with that as it removes (unnecessary) details from a subprogram header making it a bit more abstract.